# When does redirect occur after issuing HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute in Authorize filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following in an MVC 3 Authorize action filter:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoute("OrganizationRoute", new { controller = "Home", action = "OrganizationList" });
```

When does the redirect occur?  Immediately after the above statement is executed?  Or after the action filter exits?  (Or never?)

And if the redirect doesn't occur until after the filter exits, what happens if I invoke another RedirectToRoute before it exits?  That is, I invoke RedirectToRoute two (or more) times in the filter - perhaps with different parameters - and then exit.

Does the last one invoked take effect?  Or ???

DadCat

Comment: Why won't you try and tell us the answer?

Comment: Based on articles I just found, I **suspect** I should be setting filterContext.result to an instance of RedirectToRouteResult, rather than calling RedirectToRoute. But it would be nice if someone could confirm this!